# How to migrate volume of statefulset to a helm chart

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-helm

I have a functionning zookeeper stateful set, i have manually created.
I want to migrate to a helm installation of zookeeper.

My kubernetes cluster run on aws.

How to migrate volume from one stateful to the other ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called "[chartify](https://github.com/appscode/chartify)", that can generate Helm Charts from an existing Kubernetes api objects.
 It works both as a Helm plugin or as a stand-alone tool.

Please mind that there is already a Helm chart for zookeeper in the [incubator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/zookeeper) repository.